# Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for SigningConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

**ERROR**

> Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for
> SigningConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null,
> storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=pkcs12,
> v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null,
> enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null} of
> type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig$AgpDecorated.

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'kotlin-android'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 32
    
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sonkhiasinghansh.groceryapp"
            minSdk 19
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    
                minifyEnabled false
    
    
                proguardFiles(
                        getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                )
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        packagingOption {
            exclude 'META-INF/atonicfu.kotlin_module'
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    
        def room_version = "2.2.1"
        def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    
        // Room and Architectural Components
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
        implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
        kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    
        // Coroutines
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1"
    
        // New Material Design
        implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"
    
        // ViewModel
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
        //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
        kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might be of help.
To start with, ensure you have generated an upload-keystore.jks file.

• This requires java JDK Installed.
• Open the Java JDK Installation path in the command line [PS, You can also add an ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE for Java JDK. Follow [This Guide:](https://www.guru99.com/install-java.html#:%7E:text=Step%201%29%20Right%20Click%20on%20the%20My%20Computer,bin%20folder%20which%20is%20installed%20in%20JDK%20folder.)

And paste the command below.

For Mac:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

For Windows:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Move the generated upload-keystore.jks file to your \android\app directory.

After this, create a key.properties file in your \android directory [if you have not created one yet],  which should be as such:

```
storePassword=yourstorepasswordhere // no single or double quotes
keyPassword=yourkeypasswordhere // no single or double quotes
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=upload-keystore.jks  // if you placed it in the android\app directory (Recommended). Else enter the path to your upload-keystore.jks
```

Right before the android {} block in your app level build.gradle [android\app\build.gradle], add this:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

**Rebuild your project.**

And there you have it. Hope this helps.